# Deploying DevExpress (third party) controls on SharePoint

Tags: 2007, third-party-software, assembly-references

I don't know whether anyone is familiar with DevExpress controls, but I am trying to implement their [ASPxScheduler](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Scheduler/) within SharePoint.

What I have done so far is:

- Register the required assemblies in the GAC on the server
- Added the assemblies in the web.config
- Added HttpHandlerModule to web.config
- Added the assemblies as safe controls
- Registered the assemblies on the aspx page

This seems to be working so far, but the ASPxScheduler requires other ascx controls, and their code behind files, to be added to the site. I have added these at thge correct location (root of the site) and it seems to be picking them up. But as they are not built I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'HorizontalAppointmentTemplate'.

Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="HorizontalAppointmentTemplate" Codebehind="HorizontalAppointmentTemplate.ascx.cs" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v10.2, Version=10.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler" TagPrefix="dxwschs" %>
Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.2, Version=10.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dxe" %>
```

I have read into a few things and some say that I need to build the site locally and copy the dll's over but SharePoint Designer doesn't have an option to build and Visual Studio won't open SharePoint sites.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the problem is on line 1. There you specify an `Inherits` attribute together with the `Codebehind` attribute.
You probably can't specify them togheter as specified here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Also, if you specify the `Inherits` attribute, you have to specify the full qualified name of your type in line 1:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="HorizontalAppointmentTemplate, <AssemblyName>, <Version>, <Culture>, <PublicKeyToken>" Codebehind="HorizontalAppointmentTemplate.ascx.cs" %>
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah I saw that, it works in my local machine, but it doesn't have .Net 3.5. However, how do I get the assembly info when I can't build the files?

Comment: Ok, your answer helped me get this working. I removed all the `Inherits` from the acsx files and put in `<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/DevExpress/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>` into the web.config `PageParserPaths` section. It now works. thanks for your help. Now need to work out how to fix the styling!